# jQuery Plugin Colorbox: Problem - won't work anymore

Tags: jquery, plugins, colorbox

I've been working for days on the colorbox plugin. I got it to work, but I destroyed my result when I tried to use the rel Tag and couldn't find what I did wrong.

This is the HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td>City Numver</td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Street</td>
    <td>etc</td>
    <td>
        <div class="colorbox">Details
            <div style="display: none;">
                <div id="Div1" class="pop">
                    <p class="alignleft">Referenz entstand zügig.</p>
                    <img class="alignleft" src="http://www.d-krings.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/menzel-3616.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  style="display: none;">Div #2
                <div style="display: none;">
                    <div id="Div2" class="pop"><img class="alignleft" src="http://www.d-krings.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/menzel-3616.jpg" alt="" />
                        <p class="alignleft">Referenz entstand zügig.</p>
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Every Company will get a Row in the Table and by clicking "Details," you'll get Images of this Company. (see here: http://www.d-krings.de/referenzen)

And this is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("div.colorbox").colorbox({ 
        inline: true,
        href: function () {
            var elementID = jQuery(this).find('div .pop').attr('id');
            return "#" + elementID;
        }
    });
    jQuery("div.colorbox").colorbox(rel="my_group")
}
```

I simply need a link to Click on which shows the images grouped for the company. But the Images can only be seen when u clicked on the link. Not before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("div.colorbox").colorbox({ 
        rel: "my_group",
        inline: true,
        href: function () {
            var elementID = jQuery(this).find('div .pop').attr('id');
            return "#" + elementID;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The New Code after your PostjQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery("div.colorbox").colorbox({ 
  inline: true,
  href: function () {
   var elementID = jQuery(this).find('div .pop').attr('id');
   return "#" + elementID;
  }
 });
 jQuery("div.colorbox").colorbox({rel: "my_group"});

}

Comment: Normaly it should Group the Images related to the REL tag in one group. I have to use ist because every company should use theire own images.

Comment: And thanks again for ur fast answer but it won't work either. I need to build in a rel tag into the divs but i dunno how.

Comment: I simply need a link to Click on which shows the images grouped for the company. But the Images can only be seen when u clicked on the link. Not before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution i tried a bit and there it is:

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.boxpop").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).colorbox({
            html: jQuery(this).find('div').html(),
            rel: jQuery(this).attr('rel')
        });
    });
});
```

And the HTML-Code:

```
<div class="boxpop" rel="yourGroup here">Details
    <div class="bp_container" style="display:none">
        <p><img src="image.jpg"></p>
        <p class="colorbox_desc">You can use Description here.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="boxpop" rel="yourGroup here" style="display: none;">
    <div class="bp_container"  style="display:none">
        <p><img src="image.jpg"></p>
        <p class="colorbox_desc">You can use Description here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use Descriptions now. It's a Multi inline html Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Colorbox needs a way to find digital assets (like images) and group them for display. In its simplest use case, the HTML element REL is used to do that. For example, all images with the same value for REL form an array and displayed [0] thru [n].

You can override the default REL use by specifying a 'rel' parameter, which according the colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) lets you specify another grouping mechanism.

But you still have to have provide a way for colorbox to find and group together your assets.

- Kevin M.